# S3 connector with HourlyPartitioner failing

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

When we tried to write into S3 through S3 sink connector with default config, working fine without any issue. But when we tried with hourly partition getting failed with below error.
Please find the both codes and error messages and help us to resolve this issue

Default :

```
{
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "tibconew1-test-s3standard-default-sink-connector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "topics": [
    "test.s3custom.default.dax.shipment.data",
    "test.s3custom.default.dax.shipment.data",
    "test.s3custom.hourly.onprem.tibco.dax_shipment.dpp_asn"
  ],
  "topics.regex": "",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq_test.s3custom.default.dax.shipment.data",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "flush.size": "1000",
  "s3.bucket.name": "test-stg-raw",
  "s3.region": "us-east-1",
  "s3.credentials.provider.class": "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider",
  "s3.acl.canned": "bucket-owner-full-control",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "topics.dir": "streams_dir",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner"
}
```

Hourly :

```
{
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://confschema.test-dsol-core.testdigital-stg.com",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "test.s3custom.hourly.tibco.dax_shipment.dpp_asn.sink-connector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "topics": [
    "test.s3custom.hourly.onprem.tibco.dax_shipment.dpp_asn"
  ],
  "topics.regex": "",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq_test.s3custom.hourly.onprem.tibco.dax_shipment.dpp_asn.sink",
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "flush.size": "10",
  "s3.bucket.name": "test-stg-raw",
  "s3.region": "us-east-1",
  "s3.credentials.provider.class": "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider",
  "s3.acl.canned": "bucket-owner-full-control",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "topics.dir": "streams_dir",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "timezone": "America/Chicago",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "DPP_ASN.LST_UPDT_TS"
}
```

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found the reason . Due to timestamp received from the payload is an invalid format which has additional space in it.So we corrected the format in source side. For the hourly partitioner, the connector is expecting the value is based on hours.
Hourly Partitioner:

`io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner is equivalent to the TimeBasedPartitioner with path.format='year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH and`

Message  was :  `"LST_UPDT_TS":"2021-02-01 07:16:23.567"`

Corrected as : `"LST_UPDT_TS":"2015-08-01T17:00:00.69243-05:00"`